# Angular Mat-Select - openedChange returns undefined

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am setting css style using custom code when user opens mat-select. But it returns undefined error.
In console, when I print and check element values, could see panel:undefined. 
Can someone please let me know How to get the panel value.

```
Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

**Html:**

```
<mat-select #select (openedChange)="changeHeight($event,select)">
    <mat-option>1</mat-option>
    <mat-option>2</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer:Renderer2){}

changeHeight(event:any,element:any)
{
    if (event)
    {

      const height = window.innerHeight|| 
                     document.documentElement.clientHeight|| 
                     document.body.clientHeight;

      this.renderer.setStyle(element.panel.nativeElement,
          'max-height',
           (height-10-element.panel.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y)+'px')
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the version on @angular/material?

Comment: @Eliseo - Version 7. "@angular/material": "^7.2.3",

Comment: Sorry, I thought that could be a problem with the version, but, in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5grmg?file=package.json I can not reproduce the problem. You has another element with a "template reference variable"  called `#select`? (see that I choose use select but you can use `#myinput` and pass as argument `(openedChange)="changeHeight($event,myinput)"`

Comment: @Eliseo, Could you please tell me if I can use same logic for multiple mat-select. Currently I am using same code for multiple mat-select. This could be the possible reason for error.

Comment: if the mat-select are in a *ngFor, there're NO confussion, else you need give differents "template reference variable" to each one, e.g. use #select1, #select2,#select3.. and (openedChange)="changeHeight($event,select1)", (openedChange)="changeHeight($event,select2)", (openedChange)="changeHeight($event,select3)".. BTW, why not use a directive as I indicate in the second part of the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016741/how-to-adjust-mat-select-height-to-fit-its-items/62018749#62018749?

Comment: @Eliseo, Thanks much. I have used second approach and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSelect } from "@angular/material/select";
```

and this to your component:

```
@ViewChild('select') select: MatSelect;
```

Afterwards you can, if you need it, pass `select` as a parameter or just remove the parameter and call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

set elementref for element top of constructor then set the same name in your template #name with your elementref name.